# Is it ok that I ran 12-3 cable for shed mini split from shed sub panel to AC disconnect instead of 12-2?

Tags: shed, mini-split

I have a 240v LG mini split that uses 15 amp breaker.  It only needs two lines and a ground.  I mistakenly ran 12-3 when I should have run 12-2. Is it okay to leave the wire In place and just not connect the white neutral to either the 220 gfci breaker, icm517 surge protector or mini split?  I would just cap them off.

I could rewire with 12-2 If necessary.  I know i could use 14-2 but prefer to wire for 20 Amps in case down the line I replace the unit.
Thanks Andy

Comment: It is okay, but would use wire nuts on both ends of neutral so there is no bare wire for a person to touch.

Comment: If you prefer 12ga  for future uses you should also prefer the unused neutral in case your future device needs it.  This is better than ok.  It's prescient.  Of what, we don't know, but one day you'll look wise.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, that's fine.  You can just cap the neutral.

It's also fine to use larger wire than is required.  You can breaker it at 15A or 20A as the heat pump's instructions direct.